# Prove that $\frac{x}{f(x)}$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose f>0 on $(1,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}} \in (1,\infty)$. Prove that $\frac{x}{f(x)}$ is decreasing on $(b,\infty)$ for some b>1.

I try to build a contradiction by showing it is not decreasing, then ...
But I don't have some concrete idea so far. Anyone can give me some hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\left(\tfrac{x}{f(x)}\right)'=\tfrac{f(x)-xf'(x)}{f(x)^2}$. Since the denominator is positive by hypothesis, this derivative has the same sign as the numerator $f(x)-xf'(x)$.

Comment: Technically, the positive denominator ensures things are well-defined (i.e., non-zero matters). A square is always non-negative anyways.

Comment: @ClementC. : Positivity, not nonnegativity, is required to be able to make this conclusion. Even if it were a product rather than a quotient, the statement would be false if one of the factors were zero.

Comment: My point is that the positivity is more crucial to having the functions *defined*. If you don't have it, you run into trouble *much* before you get to arguing about the sign of the derivative.

Answer (score 5):

I assume $f$ is differentiable.

Note that, for $g$ defined by $g(x) = \frac{x}{f(x)}$ on $(1,\infty)$ (well-defined as $f>0$ by assumption), we have that $g$ is differentiable, with
$$
g'(x) = \frac{f(x)-x f'(x)}{f(x)^2} = \frac{1}{f(x)}\left(1-\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}\right)
$$
for every $x>1$. By our other assumption, there exists $\ell>1$ such that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}\right) = 1-\ell < 0
$$
and so there exists some $b>1$ such that $\left(1-\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}\right) \leq \frac{1-\ell}{2} < 0$ for all $x>b$.

It follows that $g'(x) < 0$ for every $x>b$, allowing you to conclude.

Comment: Thanks first. I try g'(x) before, but I did't go to the second half. Now it is clear to me.

Comment: You're welcome. If this is in the context of an exercise, do not forget to justify why things are well-defined and differentiable. Thay sounds tedious, but is quite important.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are given $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)} > 1$ then I assume $f$ must be differentiable, since otherwise that given condition just wouldn't make sense.

Consider then $$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac x{f(x)}\right) = \frac{f(x) - xf'(x)}{f(x)^2} = \frac1{f(x)}\left(1 - \frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}\right).$$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)} > 1$, there must be some value of $b$ such that...

Can you take it from here?